# javascript onsubmit = function yielding 'unable of the property to set onsubmit: object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript

Title basically says it all.

The error I get at:

```
document.forms[0].onsubmit = validateForm;
```

This is at the very top of my .js file.  Does that matter?

> Unable to set value of the property 'onsubmit': object is null or undefined

in IE's debugger.

As a test, I set the `validateForm()` to always `true`, and I still got the error.  I am positive there is a `document.forms[0]` in my webpage, and I do have a function `validateForm()`.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is your code in side window.onload?

Comment: The error seems to indicate that `document.forms[0]` does not exist at that moment. So, how did you test that it does?

Comment: If you put the javascript in the head of the document without waiting until the body is fully loaded (or even in the body before the form is loaded) you would get this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have any forms loaded at that point...
Try:

```
  window.onload = function () {
    document.forms[0].onsubmit = validateForm;
  }
```